# Is there a way to select a field to be returned when using the getList() function within a Repository?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, collection, service-contract

MAGENTO v2.2.6

To better illustrate my question here's an example. When using the ordinary collection I can limit the attributes/fields returned like so:

NOTE: I wouldn't normally use the object manager directly, this is just an example from an ad-hoc script I created.

```php
$productCollection = $objectManager->get(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::class);
$productCollection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku') /*<-- THIS IS THE FUNCTIONALITY I WANT TO MIMIC*/
    ->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer', ['eq' => 3])
    ->addFieldToFilter('price',['eq' => 234]);

foreach ($productCollection as $product){
    print_r($product->getData());
}
```

The above will return the following values from my particular store:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 185
    [attribute_set_id] => 15
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => SKY-5001
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2012-11-08 23:52:51
    [updated_at] => 2018-11-13 12:38:30
    [manufacturer] => 3
    [price] => 234.0000
)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 186
    [attribute_set_id] => 15
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => SKY-5010
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2012-08-11 23:52:54
    [updated_at] => 2018-11-13 12:38:30
    [manufacturer] => 3
    [price] => 234.0000
)
...
```

When using the `getList()` function located within `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository.php` like in the code block below, all values from the entity are returned. I'd like to minimize the amount of data returned to only what is needed.

```php
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
$productSearch = $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('manufacturer', 3, 'eq')->addFilter('price', 234, 'eq')->create();
$products = $productRepository->getList($productSearch)->getItems();

foreach ($products as $product){
    print_r($product->getData());
}
```

Here's is what's returned using the `ProductRepository`:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 185
    [attribute_set_id] => 15
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => SKY-5001
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2012-11-08 23:52:51
    [updated_at] => 2018-11-13 12:38:30
    [status] => 1
    [visibility] => 4
    [manufacturer] => 3
    [price] => 234.0000
    [description] => The 5001 On/Off Fireplace Remote Control with Backlit Touch Screen
    ...
    [size_name] => 
    [parent_sku] => 
    [color_name] => 
    [shape_name] => 
    [material_name] => 
    [inchoo_meta_robots] => 
    [mpn] => SKY-5001
    [banner_filename] => 
    [banner_category_url] => 
    [shipping_standard] => Order by 1 PM CST for Same Day Shipping
    [google_name] => 
    [remote_function_filter] => 6450
    [major_category] => Fireplace Remotes
    [sub_category1] => On/Off
    [amasty_preorder_note] => 
    [amasty_preorder_cart_label] => 
    [is_recurring] => 0
    [tax_class_id] => 2
    [fuel_type] => 
...
```

I've looked through the code base to no avail. Is there a way to select only specific attributes when using the Repository's `getList()`? I know using service contracts are the best practice, and I want to make sure I follow best practices to make upgrades and such less of a headache in the future, but I don't want to have to return every attribute or field value when getting a collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after looking into this issue, it seems that there isn't currently (as of Magento v2.2.6) function that you can use to mimic the functionality of `addAttributeToSelect`. It looks like like most realistic option would be to create a custom function based on `getList()` and add in your own attributes that you'd like to select manually. Looking at the `getList()` function in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php`

```php
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); /*YOU'D WANT TO SELECT THE SPECIFIC ATTRIBUTES HERE*/
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');

        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

        $collection->load();

        $collection->addCategoryIds();
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
            $this->cacheProduct(
                $this->getCacheKey(
                    [
                        false,
                        $product->hasData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::STORE_ID) ? $product->getStoreId() : null
                    ]
                ),
                $product
            );
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
```

So if you really want to use the `Product Repository` you could extend from this class and add in your own additional custom `getList()` function (DON'T OVERWRITE THE `getList()` FUNCTION ITSELF) like `getListSku()` in my case and update the line `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')` to `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku')`.